# Detecting that a script is run within ARD

Tags: macos, remote-desktop, script, command-line

Does anyone know of a way to detect that a shell script is running within ARD (vs. running the same script locally on the machine)?

I looked at detecting that we are running in interactive mode - that fails, since both are noninteractive.

I'm looking at the $0 variable, which looks more promising - it returns `-bash` when run from the command line, returns the name of the script when running within a script run locally, and returns `/bin/bash` when run via ARD. However - I'm not certain whether those effects can be counted on.

Does anyone have any input on this?

Answer (score 4):

Why not pass in an extraneous argument when you issue a command from ARD.

It's more a workflow than a system generated tag, but ARD likely sends the same command to launchd as the `open -a` command would so that level of indirection means that you can't depend on the typical ppid from `ps -ef` to find the process that forked a specific script.

Why not push a wrapper script to all your machines and use that wrapper script to log the arguments to console? Then ARD can call the wrapper script.

Something like a script stored in `/usr/local/bin/remote` would work well:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "This script was called remotely and is about to run another script."
/bin/bash $*
echo "This script has just run another script."
```

You can get all fancy with [parsing the arguments](http://osr600doc.sco.com/en/SHL_automate/_Passing_to_shell_script.html) or using `logger` and/or date/time stamping or recording which computer did the sending, but this is a common way to track execution of other scripts.

Comment: Thanks, I may resort to that - though I had been hoping that I could seamlessly use the same script in both places - it needs to act differently in each place. I'm looking through the environment variables, and may have found a couple options that may be sufficient for my needs (COLUMNS or TERM) - though I'm still interested in a proper method, if it exists...

Comment: @Scot  Here's an [example of parsing arguments from a shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895658/shell-script-with-arguments-presented) if you're not familiar with that side of scripting.

Comment: Thanks again. For the purposes of this script, I wanted to have the logic built-in to the script itself, so I ended up using the environment variable TERM (it is dumb when running a script within ARD, and xterm-256color when running locally. So far this has been a good enough hook...